# Position of Devatas in Panchayatana Pooja

Tags: worship, adi-shankaracharya, smarta

The Narada Purana III.65.44-50 states:-

> "44-50.When he worships Visnu in the middle, he shall worship Vinayaka,Ravi(Sun) Siva and Sivaa outside them. When he worships Sankara in the middle, he shall worship the Sun, Ganesa, Amba and Hari outside them. When he worships Siva in the middle, he shall worship Isa, Vighnesvara, the Sun and Govinda outside.If he worships Gananayaka (Ganesa) in the middle he shall worship Siva, Sivaa, the Sun and Visnu outside. When the Sun is worshipped in the middle he shall worship GaneSa, Visnu, Amba, and Siva respectively. Thus he shall worship respectfully the five deities every day".

One such representation is shown in this picture.
[image]

I am looking for clear directions/definitions of positions of the outer devatas. For example, when Vishnu in the middle, whether Ganesha goes in north-west or south-west corner, which corner Surya goes and so on. There seems to be lot of variations on which Devata is placed in which corner. Any scriptural statements to support this, or any Acharya's statements supporting are welcome.